# SwiftUI navigation doesn't work when updating struct

Tags: swiftui

I have a list of structs. Tapping a button will call a mutating function on a struct, then navigate.

The navigation however won't trigger. It'll start working again if the call to the mutating function `self.logins[index].updateLastLogin()` is removed. Why?

To reproduce, paste the following in an empty SwiftUI project:

```
struct Login: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var lastLogin: Date?

    mutating func updateLastLogin() {
        self.lastLogin = Date()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var logins = ["Zaphod", "Arthur", "Ford", "Marvin", "Trillian"].map { Login(name: $0) }
    @State private var selection: Login?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.logins) { login in
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text(login.name).font(.largeTitle),
                                       tag: login,
                                       selection: self.$selection) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            self.navigate(login: login)
                        }, label: {
                            Text(login.name)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func navigate(login: Login) {
        guard let index = self.logins.firstIndex(of: login) else {
            fatalError()
        }

        self.logins[index].updateLastLogin() // remove this line
        self.selection = login
    }
}
```

Comment: `selection` must be one of `tag`(s) then the corresponding link is activated - that's the purpose.

Comment: @Asperi But even if you put the line with "updateLastLogin" as the last line in the navigate function, it still doesn't work. Because if your remark, I understand that the hash of the login changed and thus the tag no longer is the same. But still if the mutating function was called AFTER setting the selection, I'd expect it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of working approach. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var logins = ["Zaphod", "Arthur", "Ford", "Marvin", "Trillian"].map { Login(name: $0) }
    @State private var selection: UUID?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.logins) { login in
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text(login.name).font(.largeTitle),
                                       tag: login.id,
                                       selection: self.$selection) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            self.navigate(login: login)
                        }, label: {
                            Text(login.name)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func navigate(login: Login) {
        guard let index = self.logins.firstIndex(of: login) else {
            fatalError()
        }

        self.logins[index].updateLastLogin() // remove this line
        self.selection = login.id
    }
}
```

Comment: I've accepted the answer because obviously you put in some effort. My remaining question is: why wouldn't it work if I mutated the struct AFTER assigning it to the `selection` variable ?

Comment: It is exactly because selection is called *after* modification, because after modification `logins` array does not contain any more  *login* value (your `struct Login` is-a struct, not a class), and modified array rebuilds List, because it is a State, so List contains links with new updated tags, but you assign to selection old one, thus nothing happens.

Comment: Ooooooh yeah... thanks for making the penny drop   •ᴗ•