# I'm having an issue changing Views in SwiftUI using an if/else statement for a login view

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, swiftui

I'm having trouble changing views when a username and password is successfully entered. I know the username and password works because the print statement is executed. Its a basic login type form.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {
    @ObservedObject var networkManager: NetworkManager = NetworkManager()
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Image("dashlogovert")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 280.0, height: 280.0, alignment: .top)
                Form {
                    TextField("Username", text: $username)
                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    Button(action: {
                        self.AttempLogin()
                        })
                        {
                            Text("Login")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .frame(width: 300, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                                .font(.title)
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color(red: 132/255, green: 203/255, blue: 161/255))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Login")
        }
    }
    func AttempLogin(){
        self.networkManager.loginFunction(username: self.username, password: self.password){
            if self.networkManager.loggedIn {
                print("You are logging in");
                Dashboard()
            } else {
                print("You aren't logging in");
                FailedLogin()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

Dashboard() is the new view I will take the user to when they successful logon, and fail is also a view.
Also what is the best way to do this if I have done it a really bad way.

Comment: Views should be in `body` not in closure. You should navigate conditionally. Next should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/63346361/12299030.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass back your logged in state from `loginFunction()` using `@escaping closure` if it’s `asynchronous` task, and once you have that state you can pass it back to your view body by using `closure` again as a parameter in `AttemptLogin()` function, and assign that new state value to `@State` property wrapper, which will call body refresh and check for updated state.

Check below code-:

```
import SwiftUI

enum LoginState:String {
    case failed
    case success
    case unknownState
}

class NetworkManager:ObservableObject{
    
    func loginFunction(username:String,password:String,closure: @escaping (String)->()){
        closure(LoginState.failed.rawValue)
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    @ObservedObject var networkManager: NetworkManager = NetworkManager()
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State var isLoggedIn:String = LoginState.unknownState.rawValue
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Image("dashlogovert")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 280.0, height: 280.0, alignment: .top)
                Form {
                    TextField("Username", text: $username)
                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    Button(action: {
                        self.AttempLogin { state in
                            isLoggedIn = state
                        }
                    })
                    {
                        Text("Login")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color(red: 132/255, green: 203/255, blue: 161/255))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    
                    if isLoggedIn == LoginState.success.rawValue{
                        Dashboard()
                    }
                    
                    if isLoggedIn == LoginState.failed.rawValue{
                        FailedLogin()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Login")
        }
    }
    func AttempLogin(_ closure: @escaping (String)->()){
        self.networkManager.loginFunction(username: self.username, password: self.password){ loginState in
            if loginState == LoginState.success.rawValue {
                print("You are logging in");
                closure(loginState)
            }
            
            if loginState == LoginState.failed.rawValue {
                print("You aren't logging in");
                closure(loginState)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Dashboard:View{
    var body: some View{
        Text("Dashboard")
    }
}

struct FailedLogin:View{
    var body: some View{
        Text("Login")
    }
}

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

I have taken `NetworkManager` and other classes as dummy on my side.You need to write your logic accordingly.